# Selenium with Java error :"File path wcxChrome.crx needs to be absolute in key ..."

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm new to Selenium, and I am doing some SeleniumDriver practices on Java, following the example code on "https://saucelabs.com/resources/articles/getting-started-with-webdriver-selenium-for-java-in-eclipse".

I followed the instructions but I got an error. Here is the code block:

```
@Test
public void site_header_is_on_home_page() {

    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe");

    WebDriver browser = new ChromeDriver();

    browser.get("https://www.saucelabs.com");

    WebElement href = browser.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@href='/beta/login']"));

    assertTrue((href.isDisplayed()));

    browser.close();       

}
```

> **The error message is:**
>
> [17200:25400:0515/151552.506:ERROR:external_registry_loader_win.cc(152)]

---

> File path wcxChrome.crx needs to be absolute in key
>   Software\Google\Chrome\Extensions\mjdepfkicdcciagbigfcmdhknnoaaegf

Can someone help me fix this? Many thanks!

Comment: The error reffers to Word Capture extension. First of all try to get rid of it.

Comment: Btw: before locating an element you need the page fully loaded. See for example http://www.software-testing-tutorials-automation.com/2014/01/how-to-wait-for-element-to-be-clickable.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appeared that the problem was because I gave the link to Chrome, not the ChromeDriver. I changed the path to ChromeDriver and it worked fine.